Record for determining complete list of imaginary quadratic fields with small class number
In 2003, Mark Watkins (Class numbers of imaginary quadratic fields) determined all imaginary quadratic fields having class number at most 100.
Has this list been improved? That is, what is the largest positive integer $M$ for which all imaginary quadratic fields having class number at most $M$ have been fully determined?

Did you try looking at the papers that reference the one you cited above, say using MathSciNet?  Have you looked at the paper "Missing class groups and class number statistics for imaginary quadratic fields"?

@PaceNielsen I checked the paper you mentioned; it was useful! Unfortunately it seems that their computations are dependent on GRH, so while it technically gives the correct answer (if one is willing to believe GRH) it does not give any ideas on how to obtain the (unconditional) bounds I need, as in Watkins' paper.
